# Memory error while caching heavy data with Django

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, django-sessions

I'm using Django in order to archive a web with dynamically generated images from a big image stack (around 150mb each). It's suppose to be interactive so I need to keep cached the selected stack. For this, I'm using the memcached cache backend and the "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache" session engine.

The problem is that when I render the page with the session data I keep getting MemoryError.
Is this the more efficient approach?
I'm supposing that is a problem with the size of the data. Is anyway of increase the memory size? Another way of solving this?

In views.py

```
def images(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        info_form = InfoForm(request.POST)

        if (info_form.is_valid()):

            if selected_stack_changed:
                matrix = get_matrix(stack_id)
                request.session['matrix'] = matrix
            else:
                matrix = request.session['matrix']

    return render(request, url)
```

In settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

And here the complete error i get:

```
Internal Server Error: /data/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 50, in process_response
request.session.save()
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py", line 62, in save
self.get_expiry_age())
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 83, in set
if not self._cache.set(key, value, self.get_backend_timeout(timeout)):
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 740, in set
return self._set("set", key, val, time, min_compress_len, noreply)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1060, in _set
return _unsafe_set()
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1034, in _unsafe_set
store_info = self._val_to_store_info(val, min_compress_len)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 998, in _val_to_store_info
pickler.dump(val)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Someone might be able to help you if you actually showed how you used memcached! But please note that it's not designed to hold very large objects. The default max object size is 1MB can be increased though.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the memcached server should not be on the same host as your web server. A standard memcached installation will have multiple memcached instances be running standalone on its own individual servers located close to the web servers and the web servers talking to them over the network. More elaborate installations will have multiple memcached instances managed by a proxy which routes requests to memcached server hosts. One popular proxy to do this is [Mcrouter](https://github.com/facebook/mcrouter).